# How can I refactor the code in order to use virtual method from an WebAPI?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the main class "Car" with its properties and:

```
public virtual void PrintCar()
{
  Console.WriteLine(Brand + " " + ManufactureYear);
}
```

The derived class "Electric" overrides the "PrintCar" method and prints some info.
I also added a minimal web API with Swagger to essentially call the "PrintCar" method and give it an id:

```
app.MapGet("/cars/{id}", (int id) => Car.PrintCar(id));
```

I want specifically to use ID because "Car" class has a method that can construct a different object based on the given ID.
Is there any way I can change the virtual method from "Car" class in order to receive the "PrintCar" info from the derived class?

Comment: Are you just asking how to add an `int` parameter to your method?  It's not really clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: @David not really, I tried to create a `public virtual string PrintCar(int id)` but this means the derived class method should also be changed in order to match the main class method.

Comment: Indeed it should.  Method signatures need to match when overriding them, inheriting them, calling them, etc.  If you need a method that's unique only to the base `Car` class and not its inheriting classes, why not just create a separate method on that class?  It's still not clear what the underlying problem is.

Comment: The issue is that when I use the GET verb with an ID from Swagger, the virtual method should create an object based on ID (can be Electric/Diesel/Gasoline car) and access the overridden method from the derived class and print some info specific to the car type. @David

Comment: If you need a method which accepts a parameter and a method which does not then you need two methods.  The code shown is very minimal and doesn't really demonstrate the underlying need, but from a language perspective different methods are different.  The method with the parameter can *internally* call the method without the parameter.  But no matter how you organize it... If you want a method which accepts an integer then you need to write a method which accepts an integer.

Comment: I understand, will try to be more specific next time. I will add another method and maybe get the wanted result. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Having read this post and comments, I'm not sure if you clearly understand OOP. First of all, why do you want Print() method to create a car? It should not to this. If I understand your problem, you want to have Electric/Diesel/Gasoline car depending on given id? If so, this is good place for using factory. Let me know if this is your issue. If so, I can post this as an answer with more details.